# Difference between ObjectManager and EntityManager in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

What's the difference between `Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager` and `Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager` when using it in a custom form type?

I can get the respository using both `$this->em->getRepository()` and `$this->om->getRepository()`.

```
class MyFormType extends \Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType
{

    /**
     * @var Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
     */
    protected $em;

    public function __construct(Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

 }
```

Instead of:

```
class MyFormType extends \Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType
{

    /**
     * @var Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager
     */
    protected $om;

    public function __construct(Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager $om)
    {
        $this->om = $om;
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 112, accepted):

`ObjectManager` is an interface and `EntityManager` is its ORM implementation. It's not the only implementation; for example, `DocumentManager` from MongoDB ODM implements it as well. `ObjectManager` provides only the common subset of all its implementations.

If you want your form type to work with any `ObjectManager` implementation, then use it. This way you could switch from ORM to ODM and your type would still work the same. But if you need something specific that only `EntityManager` provides and aren't planning to switch to ODM, use it instead.

Comment: I think the use of EntityManager is now deprecated, or at least its use in a dependency injection. But there's still EntityManagerInterface if I'm correct, and I don't know the difference between Objectmanager and EntityManagerInterface.